# EKEventStore remove sync issue with one O365 calendar on multiple iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, events, calendar, eventkit

I have an issue with removing events from local O365 calendar on iOS devices:
I have two iOS devices connected to the same O365 calendar. Calendar is working fine.

**1. Creating a new event will sync to a second device immediately**

```
try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
```

This will immediately syncing the new created event with O365 and the second device is receiving a notification and also displaying the just new created event - fine

**2. Deleting any event on one device does not sync on second device immediately**

```
try eventStore.remove(event, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
```

This will delete the event in the local calendar and also syncing it with O365. So the event is removed. Anyhow the second device still continues with displaying the already deleted event. There is no notification for deleted events.

I also tried

```
eventStore.refreshSourcesIfNecessary()
```

but no chance to sync the calendar.

If I create another new event the second iOS device will recognize it immediately and after a couple of minutes also recognize that one event was already removed - anyhow not immediately.

I am fetching the events with:

```
var eventsPredicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, calendars: [calendar])
```

Any idea how to force a sync like the pull down function in the calendar app?

thx for your support
jvc